# Python matplotlib trend line with string x axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts

I'm trying to graph a set of data I have my y values as

```
y=[129.000, 128.000, 140.000, 150.000]
x=["1/2018", "2/2018", "3/2018", "4/2018"]
# plot the data itself
pylab.plot(x,y,‘o’)
# calc the trendline (it is simply a linear fitting)
z = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = numpy.poly1d(z)
pylab.plot(x,p(x),“r–”)
# the line equation:
print “y=%.6fx+(%.6f)”%(z[0],z[1])
```

I keep getting:

```
ufunc 'add' did not contain loop with signature matching type dtype ('S32') ('S32') ('S32')
```

I have tried using epoch dates as well but that didn’t work. I’m simply trying to plot a trend of prices to dates and extend the trend line past the dates. I know the error has to do with the labels being strings. I’m not sure how to plot the trendline with string labels. The guide I was using has date labels so I’m not sure what I’m doing wrong.

http://widu.tumblr.com/post/43624347354/matplotlib-trendline

Any thoughts?

Comment: Which line caused the error?  You should always post the complete Traceback (formatted as code)

Comment: I doubt you can use strings to fit anything. The page you link to may not be the most reliable source. Better look at respective questions like e.g. [ths one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838037/python-matplotlib-axis-is-blank-for-date-with-trend-line).

Comment: [Curve fitting to a time series ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17638137/2823755)

Comment: then is there a way to have matplotlib convert epoch times to dates on the labels only so I could use epoch values for the graphing but have it display month values on the x axis?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea when you talk about "converting epoch times to dates on the labels only". [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35689789/4738637), you can see how to convert datetimes to numbers using Matplotlib's native date2num and then adjust the plot to display the X-axis tick marks as dates.

```
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy
import dateutil
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=[129.000, 128.000, 140.000, 150.000]
xStrings=["1/2018", "2/2018", "3/2018", "4/2018"]

# Convert strings to datetime objects,and then to Matplotlib date numbers
dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(x) for x in xStrings]
x = mdates.date2num(dates)

# plot the data itself
pylab.plot(x,y,'o')

# calc the trendline (it is simply a linear fitting)
z = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = numpy.poly1d(z)

polyX = numpy.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)
pylab.plot(polyX,p(polyX),"r")
# the line equation:
print("y=%.6fx+(%.6f)"%(z[0],z[1]))

# Show X-axis major tick marks as dates
loc= mdates.AutoDateLocator()
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(loc))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

pylab.show()
```