# Creating a weekly profile in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"on": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]}, 
              index=pd.date_range(start = "2020-04-09 6:45", periods = 30, freq = '8H'))
```

and want to create a weekly profile for the column `df['on']`.

I can insert the weekdays and times as follows:

```
df['day_name'] = df.index.day_name() 
df['time'] = df.index.time
```

and geht this df:

```
                    on  day_name    time
2020-04-09 06:45:00 1   Thursday    06:45:00
2020-04-09 14:45:00 1   Thursday    14:45:00
2020-04-09 22:45:00 1   Thursday    22:45:00
2020-04-10 06:45:00 1   Friday      06:45:00
2020-04-10 14:45:00 1   Friday      14:45:00
2020-04-10 22:45:00 0   Friday      22:45:00
2020-04-11 06:45:00 0   Saturday    06:45:00
2020-04-11 14:45:00 0   Saturday    14:45:00
2020-04-11 22:45:00 1   Saturday    22:45:00
2020-04-12 06:45:00 0   Sunday      06:45:00
2020-04-12 14:45:00 0   Sunday      14:45:00
2020-04-12 22:45:00 1   Sunday      22:45:00
2020-04-13 06:45:00 1   Monday      06:45:00
2020-04-13 14:45:00 0   Monday      14:45:00
2020-04-13 22:45:00 0   Monday      22:45:00
2020-04-14 06:45:00 0   Tuesday     06:45:00
2020-04-14 14:45:00 0   Tuesday     14:45:00
2020-04-14 22:45:00 1   Tuesday     22:45:00
2020-04-15 06:45:00 0   Wednesday   06:45:00
2020-04-15 14:45:00 1   Wednesday   14:45:00
2020-04-15 22:45:00 1   Wednesday   22:45:00
2020-04-16 06:45:00 0   Thursday    06:45:00
2020-04-16 14:45:00 0   Thursday    14:45:00
2020-04-16 22:45:00 0   Thursday    22:45:00
2020-04-17 06:45:00 1   Friday      06:45:00
2020-04-17 14:45:00 1   Friday      14:45:00
2020-04-17 22:45:00 1   Friday      22:45:00
2020-04-18 06:45:00 0   Saturday    06:45:00
2020-04-18 14:45:00 0   Saturday    14:45:00
2020-04-18 22:45:00 0   Saturday    22:45:00
```

can someone help me how to get the probability that for a certain time (e.g. tuesday, 22:45) the column `df['on'] == 1`? And this is best done as a course for the whole week...
(In this example the probability for thursday, 22:45 is: 1/2)

Thanks alot :)

Comment: Can you explian how is count `2/3` from sample data?

Comment: Yes of course: @ tuesday 22:45 the column `df['on']` is 2x 1 and 1x 0 --> probability for on = 2/3

Comment: I ask because I see only `1x1` and`2x0

Comment: sorry i guess i got a little confused with tuesday and thursday. The correct probability for thursday, 22:45 is 1/2. Thanks for drawing attention to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I considered two options in your question:

**1. Ratio per week day**:
I calculated the ratio (probability) that the column `'on'==1` for a given day:

**Ratio per weekday:**

```
df_2=pd.DataFrame()
df_2['Ones']=df[df['on']==1]['day_name'].value_counts()
df_2['All']=df['day_name'].value_counts()
df_2['Ratio']=df_2['Ones']/df_2['All']
df_2
```

Here's the output:

```
        Ones    All Ratio
Friday     5    6   0.833333
Thursday   3    6   0.500000
Wednesday  2    3   0.666667
Monday     1    3   0.333333
Saturday   1    6   0.166667
Sunday     1    3   0.333333
Tuesday    1    3   0.333333
```

**2. Ratio per day per time**:
Here i calculated the probability that on day "x" at time "y", the column `"on"` would be 1:

**Ratio per week day and time:**

```
df_3 = df.groupby(['day_name', 'time']).agg({'on': 'count'})
df_3['ones'] = df.groupby(['day_name', 'time']).agg({'on': 'sum'})
df_3['Ratio'] = df_3['ones']/df_3['on']
df_3
```

Here's the output:

```
                  on    ones    Ratio
day_name    time            
Friday  06:45:00    2   2   1.0
        14:45:00    2   2   1.0
        22:45:00    2   1   0.5
Monday  06:45:00    1   1   1.0
        14:45:00    1   0   0.0
        22:45:00    1   0   0.0
Saturday06:45:00    2   0   0.0
        14:45:00    2   0   0.0
        22:45:00    2   1   0.5
Sunday  06:45:00    1   0   0.0
        14:45:00    1   0   0.0
        22:45:00    1   1   1.0
Thursday06:45:00    2   1   0.5
        14:45:00    2   1   0.5
        22:45:00    2   1   0.5
Tuesday 06:45:00    1   0   0.0
        14:45:00    1   0   0.0
        22:45:00    1   1   1.0
Wednesday06:45:00   1   0   0.0
        14:45:00    1   1   1.0
        22:45:00    1   1   1.0
```

### Probabily Plotting

To answer your request, I had to do some modifications of the code above: I needed to sort the indexes as requested, merged them into one index then converted the index into strings to avoid some problems in the plotting. Here's the new code:

#Ratio per week day and time

```
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
df_3 = df.groupby(['day_name', 'time']).agg({'on': 'count'})
df_3['ones'] = df.groupby(['day_name', 'time']).agg({'on': 'sum'})
df_3['Ratio'] = df_3['ones']/df_3['on']
df_3 = df_3.reindex(days, level=0)
df_3.index = [str(i) for i in (df_3.index.map('{0[0]} : {0[1]}'.format))]
df_3
```

Now that we did the previous modefications, we can easily plot the Ratio:

#Graph for probabilities

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()

plt.plot(df_3.index, df_3['Ratio'])
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.title('Probability of "on"=1')
```

Here's the graph:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. Your 2. option is perfect. can you also help me to create a diagram of the probabilities ( `df2['ratio']`) over a week (starting on Monday) from the 2nd option? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. I updated my answer to provide the graph you asked for. You can change the type of the graph as you want. Good Luck!

Comment: thank you very much - your answers are perfekt. Do you know, if its possible, that only the days @ 14:45:00 are shown in the plot x-axis?

Comment: You're welcome.
I'm sorry, I'm not sure I know a simple way to do that. Except if you want to manualy manipulate the list of x-values.

Comment: No problem. I'm using now this `plt.xticks(np.arange(0, len(df_3.index), step=3), rotation = 90)` and thats enough for me!
sorry for the next question, but do you also know, how to create a trendline for this plot? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I used this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50474104/python-matplotlib-trend-line-with-string-x-axis-labels) to answer your question. This code works for me: 

`dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(i) for i in df_3.index]
x = mdates.date2num(dates)
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.plot(df_3.index, p(x),"r--")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried your code, but getting at the line `dates = ...` following error: `Unknown string format: Monday : 06:45:00` and don't know how to fix it. Can you help me?

Comment: Yes change this code line `df_3.index = [str(i) for i in (df_3.index.map('{0[0]} : {0[1]}'.format))]` into this `df_3.index = [str(i) for i in (df_3.index.map('{0[0]}, {0[1]}'.format))]` and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `mean` only:

```
df1 = df.groupby('day_name', sort=False, as_index=False)['on'].mean()
print (df1)
    day_name        on
0   Thursday  0.500000
1     Friday  0.833333
2   Saturday  0.166667
3     Sunday  0.333333
4     Monday  0.333333
5    Tuesday  0.333333
6  Wednesday  0.666667
```